# Why is WordPress only hooking some of my stylesheet and not Bootstrap CDN?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to put the finishing touches on a website I built but I'm having trouble linking my stylesheets with php. If you go to the website (www.mustafasprojects.com) you will see no navbar and a contact form justified to the left. But if you inspect the page you will see there is in fact css (style.css?ver=false) for the navbar and contact form but it isn't recognized. Other elements like the spotlights have been formatted correctly but all the fonts are wrong and buttons are missing. 
I suspect the navbar and contact form are messed up because the bootstrap cdn isn't properly enqueued in wordpress but I'm not sure about the rest of the style issues. What confuses me even more is that the fonts are loading but not the bootstrap cdn.

So here's me hooking in the bootstrap cdn and fonts

```
function theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'b_css', 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
```

here's me hooking in the stylesheet

```
function html5blank_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), 'false', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'html5blank_styles');
```

So the expected result for the navbar is that it loads with Mustafa's Projects (the brand) off to the left and My Work off to the right. I'm pulling it from the bootstrap navbar template. the navbar is supposed to stay stickied to the top when I scroll. the navbar should be clear and hang over the banner and the brand/My Work link are white. 
The expected result for the contact form is that it is centered over the icons on the bottom. Obviously much larger than it is currently. 
Also all the buttons are missing. I'm not sure why that is. I don't think they're pulled from the cdn so I'm not sure why they are missing.

So the actual result is the navbar does not appear. The links are the right color (white) but there is no transparent navbar and instead a large white space so you can't read any of the links. Also My Work is bulleted. The navbar should load on top of the banner instead of being a large white space. 
The contact form has been justified super hard to the left. So much so that the email form is on top of the name form. There is a send button but it should be a large, clear button that says "submit". 
The fonts are wrong but I'm not sure if that's my personal stylesheet not getting linked or the bootstrap cdn being improperly enqueued. 
also can anyone tell me why wordpress is adding empty

tags to my website?

Comment: Your stylesheets are loading fine. You might want to take a look at `style.css` and make sure everything in there is valid.

Comment: Check if the function is being called (`die('called');` inside it) and look for errors in the browser console.

Comment: @hungerstar the stylesheets are loaded but not being recognized. Everything is valid in the .html version. but the navbar, contact form and others are all in bootstrap containers and I suspect they're not appearing because the cdn isn't loading.

Comment: You included `bootstrap-theme.min.css` but not `bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: @ClaytonLeis thanks! that solved the bootstrap issue!